# How to distinguish difference between phone and tablet on Nomad for Android

Tags: lotus-formula, hcl-notes

I'm interested on how to distinguish the difference between a phone and a tablet.
Can anybody tell me what @Platform([SPECIFIC]) returns on Android tablets?

I know what it returns on a phone, but I have no tablet device to test with.